# how can i play sound when we get new data in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to play a sound when I get new data from firebase firestore. It doesn't matter whether screen is on or off, but sound must play in the background when I get data (like a telephone ring) (app will be on). Which library will be the best to achieve it ? plz help me to choose.. My project is in react native

Answer (score 0):

Firestore's collection provides an event listener when new data is added, updated, or deleted.

```js
collection.onSnapshot(
      (querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            // Handle new added data
           //  Play sound logic here
          }
          if (change.type === "modified") {
          
          }

          if (change.type === "removed") {
           
            
          }
        });
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
      }
    );
```